# how to use awk command to find all 5 length files - and print in descending order

Tags: linux, awk, terminal

I am a computer science student. Second year of school - and I'm learning about Linux. Because of the Corona virus, I study in an independent way. During my studies I came across a question - I can't solve it.

the question:

View all files in the Letters folder with a name of 5 characters, sorted by name in descending order.

my try was using awk command:

First of all I need to get into the desired folder.
Then find all 5 size files.
Make a "pipe" and use this command:

`awk length $5 asort()`

Hope you can help me, I would be happy if you told me if my question was not there

Comment: Hello Haham. Good luck with your studies. Do you mean that the file _name_ must be five characters long, or that the file _contents_ must be five bytes long?

Comment: the file name, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd Letters      # Go to the Letters directory
ls -1dr ?????   # List in reverse order all files (or directories) with five characters in the name
```

You can use `man ls` to find out the meaning of the flags `-1`, `-d`, and `-r`. The `?????` pattern matches filenames of exactly five characters (each `?` matches a single character).